# How to make a new directory in some other directory, other than the directory in which i ran my program?

Tags: java

I am new to file handling. I am using arch Linux and in the following code I am compiling and running my code from the java directory but i want to create the new directory in the miniproject directory i tried changing the current working directory but the new directory is still made in the java directory. What is wrong with this and how do i go about doing what i want. Thanks in Advance.

```
package miniproject;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class manager{
public int password;
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String args[]){
    addgenre();
    }
    public static void addgenre (){
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the new genre to be added to 
the inventory.\nenter -1 to abort.");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    if(!(str.equals("-1"))){
        genre g = new genre(str);
        System.setProperty("/home/qwerty/Documents/codes/java/", "/home/qwerty/Documents/codes/java/miniproject/");
        File file = new File(str);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                              } 
            else 
            {
            System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }
    }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What is the point of that `System.setProperty`? You try to create a directory from the name that is entered (`str`). Unless you enter an absolute path (starting with a slash) it will be created wherever you run the program.

Comment: Thanks, i was giving the absolute path to the genre object's constructor by mistake instead of the File object(Silly me).
I solved the problem i was having thanks.